# ExtJS - How to keep "this" class object?

Tags: variables, extjs, this

my code in a Controller class of ExtJs looks like this below.

1. How do I pass the `this` object to other functions without using global variables, since I will use multiple instances of my app.
2. If it can only be done globally, how can I isolate my global variables (only for one instance)?

I use ExtJs 4.1 and DeftJs

Thanks!

#

Edit:

I want to replace `oMeasurements` with `this` in all places !

```
init: function() {
    oMeasurements = this;
    this.readConfig();
},
readConfig: function() {

         oMeasurements.httpApi.request({
               module : 'monitor',
               func  :  'getConfig',
               success: oMeasurements.readConfigCallback
         });
      },

readConfigCallback: function(oResponse) {
taskMeasurements =  {
            run: oMeasurements.output,
            interval: '1000'
            ,scope: this
         }
Ext.TaskManager.start(taskMeasurements); 
},

output: function() {
         // finally here, "this" is no more my original "this"
         console.log(this);

         oMeasurements.httpApi.request({
               module : 'monitor',
               func   : 'getMeasurementsFiles',
               success: oMeasurements.outputCallback
         });
      }
```

Comment: in `oMeasurements.httpApi.request` add `scope:this`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `scope: this` after callback definition. You're losing scope not because you're calling function from another function, but because you're using callbacks.

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly! How can I make "taskMeasurements" readable in other functions? Currently it is a global, what I dont want. I cant access it by this.taskMeasurements. taskMeasurements =  {
            run: oMeasurements.output,
            interval: '1000'
            ,scope: this
         }

Answer (score 0):

Usually there is a scope parameter in Ext function calls with callbacks.

You can also set "this" of a function using Ext.bind();

For example, if you passed a function a() to a another method and ran it, "this" would be the callee. If you called Ext.bind(a, this), when passing "a", "this" would refer to the caller.